# Android: Yeahpad Pillbox7´s idVendor?

Tags: android, eclipse, ubuntu

[image]

I am trying to run/debug and my Android-app via Eclipce on an Yeahpad Pillbox7.

My OS is Ubuntu 12.10..

From the http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html#setting-up page,

I can see I need to set the:

> sudo gedit /etc/udev/rules.d/51-android.rules

Then I need to add this:

> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="?", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

***But I can´t find the*** `ATTR{idVendor}` **for Yeahpad devies!!**

**UPDATE:**

Just use

> 18d1

So it look like this.

> SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Show connected devices by running `sudo lsusb -v`